# Alamofire multipartFormData using [String : Any] parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Hello I am trying to post a parameter and/or image. 
My parameter is a  [String : Any] with string, date, int, values. 
When I post only a parameter I use URLEncoding.default encoding. However when I need to post both parameter and image I use multipartFormData. 
My code is below

```
if url == ""{

            AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                for (key,value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }

                let jpegData = art!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
                multipartFormData.append(Data((jpegData)!), withName: "photo")

            }, to: "\(NetworkManager.rootURL)/api/add/")
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
            }
        }else{
            AF.request("\(NetworkManager.rootURL)/api/add/", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).response { (reponse) in
                let status = reponse.response!.statusCode
                if status == 200{
                    completion(200)
                }else{
                    completion(401)
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that because my parameter is a any with string date int values I get a 
`Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Int' (0x1c3f1f1e8) to 'Swift.String' (0x1c3f21390).` Is there any workaround for this? or do I have to change everything to string...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to path any value as a `String` for this to work as it's the only way to transfer it to `Data` , some others use

```
for (key, value) in parameters {
   multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the answer. I tried the above code and getting a `Type 'UInt' has no member 'utf8'`

Comment: if the above doesn't work you have to follow all strings values

Answer (score 0):

I have maked block function for Upload image with parameter to Server Using Multipart

```
//Here strUrl = YOUR WEBSERVICE URL
//postParam = post Request parameter i.e. 
//let postParam : [String : Any] = [first_name : "name"]
//imageArray = image upload array i.e.
//var imageArray : [[String:Data]] = [["image_name" : YOUR IMAGE DATA]]

func postImageRequestWithURL(withUrl strURL: String,withParam postParam: Dictionary<String, Any>,withImages imageArray:[[String:Data]], completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool, _ response:NSDictionary) -> Void)
{
   let requetURL = strURL

   Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in

    for (imageDic) in imageArray
    {
        for (key,value) in imageDic
        {
            MultipartFormData.append(value, withName:key,fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
    }

    for (key, value) in postParam
    {
        MultipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)

      // MultipartFormData.append(value, withName: key)
    }

}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: requetURL, method: .post, headers: ["Accept": "application/json"]) { (result) in

    switch result {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):

        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        })

        upload.responseJSON { response in

            let desiredString = NSString(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            print("Response ====================")

            print(desiredString!)

            if let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
            {
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                    || response.response?.statusCode == 201
                    || response.response?.statusCode == 202
                {
                    completion(true,json);
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false,json);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                completion(false,[:]);
            }
        }

    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)

        completion(false,[:]);
    }

  }
}
```

You can also upload multiple image using this
I Hope this will help...